# Windows Server 2012 - GPO settings - Security Filtering and "Authenticated Users" confusion

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, group-policy, gpo

I want to add a GPO for a few computers at first then deploy this rule to all computers when everything is confirmed OK on the test systems.
I am having troubles getting the GPO to deploy to only test computers.

I have the GPO linked to the specific OU.  (thankfully a test OU not the real OU)

I have the security filtering set to 'Authenticated Users' and the 1 computer within the test OU. (2 items in the security filtering column)
But it seems both computers in the test OU are still getting this GPO deployed instead of this single computer that is listed in the filtering.

Is 'authenticated users' the same as 'everyone' including all computers in the domain within the linked OU?

Answer (score 0):

Authenticated Users includes Computers. You need to either a) Remove Authenticated Users from the ACL all together or b) Remove the Apply Group Policy right for Authenticated Users from the ACL.